add-apt-repository ppa:openssh/openssh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openssh/openssh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1139, in connect
    address_info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1370, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.net


ubuntu 22.04 LTS

python3 --version :   Python 3.10.12


Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.net

means that you are not able to resolve the address. Now there may a couple of causes, most likely you've configured something wrong in your DNS servers or your network is not set-up. Please check your network configuration and make sure the network card is properly configured and active.
First of all check which network card you're using:
nmcli device

This should list at least two entries, one for the loopback and another for the network card you're using.
Once you have the network card name you can check which dns server is actually configured on that card by issuing
nmcli device show <card-name>

As an example, on my system :
nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION      
enp0s3           ethernet  connected               netplan-enp0s3  
lo               loopback  connected (externally)  lo              
br-4873a3029be6  bridge    connected (externally)  br-4873a3029be6 
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)  docker0         

Here, we're interested in the card enp0s3 as lo is the loopback and the other two devices are virtual devices (one is a bridge to another network, the other is a docker network bridge)
Now pick the name and run :
nmcli device show enp0s3 

The output should be something like:
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:24:B2:9B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     netplan-enp0s3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.2.15/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.2.2
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.0.2.2, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 10.0.2.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.2.3
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fd00::a00:27ff:fe24:b29b/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::a00:27ff:fe24:b29b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::2
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::2, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fd00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

Look at IP4.DNS: it's telling me it's using an internal dns (my address is 10.0.2.15, my gateway is 10.0.2.2 this means that I am in the subnetwork 10.0.2).
In case you have configured your router as your DNS server you have something similar to what I have (minus the "network numbers"). It is very common to use public DNS servers such as the ones provided in this list
If you can't make anything out of the informations you see, please provide the results of the commands I suggested above and we'll see if we can help
